# How can I call a method on my form controller from my view in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Newbie to RoR.  I can't grasp the concept of how to call a simple method on my form controller from my view.  I want to collect 2 pieces of information form the view, call a method on the form controller that will retrieve a piece of information based on the parameters, and then display the piece of information on that same view or another one.  Right now, I was trying to use a form controller instance variable to accomplish the displaying of the new piece of information--not sure how I will refresh the view to display it but that is a future hurdle.  Right now, I can click my Submit button without getting any errors but it is clearly not hitting my form controller method.
Here is my erb file for the view:

```
<h1>Enter Required Information</h1>

<%= form_tag (get_hotel_recommendation_path) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:name, "Name:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:name) %>
  <%= label_tag(:date, "Date (yyyy-mm-dd):") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:date) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %><br><br>
  <%= label_tag(:recommendation, "Recommendation:") %>
  <%= @recommended_hotel_name %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my form controller code:

```
class RecommendHotelController < ApplicationController

  @recommended_hotel_name = ''

  def collect_info

  end

  def get_hotel_recommendation
    @recommended_hotel_name = Member.recommended_hotel_name( params[:name], params[:date] )
  end

end
```

I really just want a simple and easy way to do this--not necessarily the best.  I just need a quick UI to demonstrate my model code.  And I need to get it done soon.

New form controller code:

```
class RecommendHotelController < ApplicationController

  def collect_info
  end

  def get_hotel_recommendation
    redirect_to recommend_hotel_path
  end

  protected

    helper_method :recommended_hotel_name
    def recommended_hotel_name
      unless (params[:name].nil?)
        Member.recommended_hotel_name(params[:name], params[:date])
      end
    end

end
```

Comment: What's in the log file? That will show whether it is hitting the controller action. And for which action is the view you posted?

Comment: When diagnosing problems like this, always watch `log/development.log` and see what comes through it. Most Rails developers make it a habit to watch this file during development, such as with `tail -f log/development.log` if you can do that.

Comment: Frederick, I don't see anything related to the controller in the log file.  When you ask for which action the view is posted, do you mean the put/post/get distinction?  If so, I don't have a solid grasp on those concepts when I'm not dealing with displaying or updating or adding a model object.  I just want to collect 2 strings and spit out another string.  Seems like there should be a simple way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Once the controller hands over to the view, there's no going back to call additional methods. It is the controller's job to prepare everything the view might need in advance. Once inside the `render` phase, there's no way to call controller methods.

The exception to this is helper methods which *can* be called. You need to declare any methods you want to use within your view explicitly. As an example:

```
helper_method :get_hotel_recommendation
def get_hotel_recommendation
  # ...
end
```

Helper methods can also be located inside the associated helper module, and it's a good idea to put them there if they're used *exclusively* within views.

In your case, if you're using this only once, you should probably skip the assignment to an instance variable and just return the object in question. The view would look like:

```
<%= recommended_hotel_name %>
```

The adjusted controller method:

```
class RecommendHotelController < ApplicationController
protected
  helper_method :recommended_hotel_name
  def recommended_hotel_name
    Member.recommended_hotel_name(params[:name], params[:date])
  end
end
```

It's worth noting that declaring `@recommended_hotel_name = ''` in the class context is probably not what you intend. This creates a class variable, not an instance variable. Instance variables in controllers must be defined inside the primary action method or inside a `before_filter` method. Also remember that instance variables are `nil` by default, so there's no need to initialize them to that first. An empty string and `nil` are equivalent when used within a view, everything inside `<%= ... %>` is converted to a string for you automatically.

Another thing to watch out for is leaving a space between a method name and its arguments. It should be `form_tag(...)` and not `form_tag (...)`. Normally this does not make a difference, Ruby can be very lenient, but sometimes it can subtly alter the way the arguments are interpreted leading to a lot of confusion as you try to diagnose the problem. Stylistically speaking, only keywords like `if`, `while` and `case` have a space before the brackets as these are not method calls.

As to why your form isn't working, it's not clear. Those parameters should be submitted as you intend, but maybe you're not getting the right routing. Remember it's best to stick with the standard `index`, `new`, `show`, and `edit` names unless you're doing something exotic. In this case, you should probably define this as `index` if it shows more than one record or `show` if it's always one record.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer!!  I'm not displaying a record.  I just want to collect two pieces of information from the user: name and date.  And then use those parameters in order to retrieve a string to display on the view.  I will try some of your suggestions and see if I can gerrymander it into working somehow

Comment: For the "<%= recommended_hotel_name %>" portion you recommended for the view, I won't have the recommendation until after the user has submitted the name and date, so how will this get triggered to update?

Comment: Turns out it was an error in the syntax of my route that was preventing the correct form controller method from getting called.  Hallelujah!  Now I can deal with the next million errors!  ; >

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't seem that I have access to the params in the helper method.

Comment: I pasted in the new form controller code above in my original question.

Comment: `params` should be accessible in that context. What error do you get?

Comment: No error, the params are just nil by the time my helper method is executing again to redisplay the view.  I'm guessing that it is because it is a new instance of the form controller and the params has been initialized.  I'm trying to figure out how to redisplay the screen with the new piece of information, recommended hotel, after the user enters the 2 pieces of information and clicks the submit button.

Comment: Check your `log/development.log` to see what the `params` are when they come in. If they're missing it could be you're actually not getting them in the first place, possibly due to a redirect.

Comment: I'm getting them in the first place, just not after I redirect and the view launches the helper method that I was intending to then be able to go get the hotel based on the parameters.  I'm caught between the chicken and the egg!

Comment: If you redirect, you're creating a completely new request, so you must explicitly pass those parameters along. The easiest way is to `redirect_to(some_path(:name => params[:name], :date => params[:date])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the information from a form submit in the `params` array. However, from your example, I would advise to use: form_for instead of using separate form_tags.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I had thought that form_for was only for when one was dealing with a model object though but like I said, I'm very new to this,l especially the UI part.

Comment: It can do quite a lot, and if that doesn't help, you could always fall back to `fields_for`